# Laravel's Log methods does not write in laravel.log file

Tags: laravel, logging, error-handling

I have a laravel application, and I try to write in the laravel log, but it's not working: nothing is written in the laravel.log file.

I have followed all the steps from the laravel docs, but nothing shows up in the laravel.log file.

Does anybody had any similar experience?

Comment: Permissions issues, or you've configured a non-file logger in `config/app.php`. Or you're just not calling the logger right.

Comment: You should add more details about your environment/how do you calling the logger, ...; With the current details, no one can help you!

Comment: @ceejayoz, your answer helped me answer this, I needed to set the permissions of the sorage/log directory. Please move the comment to an answer.